# Fading-in text on bottom of screen centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want this text to be shown on bottom middle of the screen, but it keeps showing on bottom left of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('div').delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
```

```css
div.hidden {          
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
    <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `width: 100%`

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it worked for you as it may help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to your css.

This causes the `div` to span the entire width of the screen, so when the text is centered, it is centered in the screen.